# 'xyz' not declared error at line where 'xyz' is being declared

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor, declaration

I'm writing a non-trivial class that holds a collection of key-value pairs and during compilation I receive a very strange error that I cannot figure out.  In a function, extremely similar to this function here, but without the context due to the complexity of the code needed, I receive the error:

```
TValue& operator[](const TKey& key) {
   TDict::Node* node = mData.Begin(); // ERROR: 'node' was not declared in this scope
                                      // -_- ... really? 
   do {
      if(node->Data.Key == key) {
         return node->Data.Value;
      }
   } while(node != mData.End());

   this->Add(key, TValue());
   return this->End()->Data.Value;
}
```

- TDict is a typedef that expands into `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> >`
- TDict::Node is visible during the compilation process.
- No other variable is called node, obviously.
- This is a member function.

I am not asking for the code needed to correct this, but rather a synopsis of potential situations where an error like this can occur.

Comment: `TDict` is typedef on template class? Show the definition, please.

Comment: Yes.  Its expands into List<TKVPair>, where TKVPair is a typedef that expands into KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Its expands into List, where TKVPair is a typedef that
>   expands into KeyValuePair.

It's dependent-name, so, you should use `typename`

```
typename TDict::Node* node = mData.Begin();
```

read [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. GCC should have move intuitive error messages. I have seen this before, but could not remember how to fix it.  Again, thank you!